# Workers can't take tasks cause "no custom resources configured"

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I'm trying to make spark standalone cluster with jupyter lab using docker.
I have docker compose:

```
version: "3.3"
volumes:
  shared-workspace:
    name: "spark-sl-file-system"
    driver: local
services:
  spark-master:
    image: cluster-apache-spark:3.2.0
    container_name: spark-master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/working-data
    environment:
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-master
      - SPARK_MASTER_HOST=spark-master
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=master
  spark-worker-a:
    image: cluster-apache-spark:3.2.0
    container_name: spark-worker-a
    ports:
      - "9091:8080"
      - "7000:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-a
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/working-data
  spark-worker-b:
    image: cluster-apache-spark:3.2.0
    container_name: spark-worker-b
    ports:
      - "9092:8080"
      - "7001:7000"
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKLOAD=worker
      - SPARK_LOCAL_IP=spark-worker-b
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/working-data
  jupyterlab:
    image: jupyter/all-spark-notebook:latest
    container_name: spark-jupyterlab
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB: "yes"
      JUPYTER_TOKEN: "docker"do
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    volumes:
      - shared-workspace:/opt/working-data
```

I'm trying to make example script:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession with master and worker config
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test") \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "1") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "1g") \
    .config("spark.driver.host", "spark-jupyterlab") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create a DataFrame with some example data
data = [("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 30), ("Charlie", 35)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Age"])

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()

# Group by age and count the number of names
result = df.groupBy("Age").count()

# Show the result
result.show()

# Stop the SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

But workers not taking tasks (exiting and take task)

```
23/04/10 11:34:06 INFO Worker: Executor app finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
23/04/10 11:34:06 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 14
23/04/10 11:34:06 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app, execId=14)
```

Master write erors:

```
App app requires more resource than any of Workers could have.
```

There is blank resource column in master ui and workers ui. But cores and memory per exuctor is not null, it shows 1 and 1024.
What can I do to solve this problem, how can I add resources?

EDIT_1:

Tried to launch task directly from master container bash, and it works.
So problem is with jupyter-lab connection.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it happened because I had ***different spark version*** in jupyter image and spark image.